# Facebook Messenger slow response time with rasa_core

Tags: python, heroku, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, rasa-core

I have a very slow response time (~3000 ms) when using **facebook messenger** with **rasa_core** while using the exact same bot on **slack** is way more responsive (~200ms).

My setup is the following:

- Rasa Core version: 0.11.12
- Python version: 3.6.6
- Operating system (windows, osx, ...): Heroku dyno
  Has anybody encountered this problem before ? apparently some people have faced the same issue with [Amazon Lambda](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=790137) but no solution was found.

Comment: Could isolate the problem, apparently it comes from the first post request : `fbmessenger.send()` using this [library](https://github.com/rehabstudio/fbmessenger)